# Image in Interface Builder with Embedded Framework

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Since I'm using the new iOS8 embedded frameworks I'm not able to use images from interface builder. I see them on that but when I compile I receive this error:

"Could not load the "nameoftheimage.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "company.project"

I think that the interface builder is searching the images in the wrong bundle. When I load something programmatically I can specify the bundle but I can't find a way to do it in the interface builder and I honestly can't believe that there is no way or I have to write tons of code to fix this.

Comment: did you get solution for this ??

Comment: Nope. I still have to copy the images in the other project or else in the Interface Builder I can't import them.

Comment: still nothing here? :/

Comment: Nope :(
Still no news.

Answer (score -2):

You need to copy the images in your framework. Then only the images are shipped as a part of your framework.

[See this screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79649352/CopyImages.png)

Comment: I already copied them and I can load them from code writing in which bundle they have to be loaded. The problem is in the Interface Builder.